# Conditional rendering is not working in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, redux

After getting data from the backend, I can't get to display is on the homepage
Everthing is okay like server, database but conditional rendering is not working
[Homepage UI with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61Z8r.jpg)

`

```
import React, {useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getAllPizzas } from "../actions/pizzaActions";
import Error from "../components/Error";
import Loading from "../components/Loading";
import Pizza from "../components/Pizza";

const Homescreen = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const pizzasstate = useSelector((state) => state.getAllPizzasReducer);
  const { pizzas, error, loading } = pizzasstate;
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getAllPizzas());
  }, [dispatch]);
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="row">
      {loading ? (
         <Loading/>
        ) : error ? (
         <Error  error='Something went wrong'/>
        ) : (
          pizzas.map((pizza) => {
            return (
              <div className="col-md-3 m-3" key={pizza._id}>
                <div>
                  <Pizza pizza={pizza} />
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          })
        )}
        
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Homescreen;
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: show the store update

Comment: You show the error because you get an error I would not consider that an issue with conditional error.

Comment: error :- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: A 404 from the server has nothing to do with react or redux. You should debug the request you're sending and why it doesn't return anything.